# What is the difference between Email and Mailing?

Tags: civimail, email, gsoc

I found that if I want to send mail to an individual, I need to use Email while in order to send mail to a group, I need to use mailing. Is this the main difference? Are there ways to schedule Email like in case of Mailings?

Also I could not find a folder for Email in Civicrm folder. Are there DAO and BAO files for Email?

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that the mails are sent "synchronously", when you save it, that sets a limit of max 50 emails, whilst the mailings are sent in the background via a cron (so you don't get any timeout and can send it to millions)

The BAO/DAO for emails are into CRM/Core

if you have installed civi from buildkit (or from git) you have a xml/schema folder that defines the structure of the tables and where the DAO are (it's from there it's generated). I find it more convenient to search than the CRM code

Answer (score 2):

This link will explain you about Email and Mailing in details 
http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/email/what-you-need-to-know/ give a quick read

Comment: Throughout StackExchange, good practice is to provide a short excerpt or summary along with a link when providing an answer. This provides readers to preview the solution before clicking, and helps protect againt link rot for future visitors.

Comment: thanks for the advice and will correct this from next time

Comment: No problem, but note that you can [edit](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/posts/2689/edit) this post as well. For additional guidance, I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour) and to review the [help center](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help) :).

Answer (score 0):

E Mail is a mean of communication which is used for purposes such as send/receive/forward and reply to text / audio or video messages.
It is sent to specific persons whom we want to send the message.
All sorts of messages/interests can be shared and discussed.
                              Whereas,
Mailing list is a group o people with similar interest.Their E mail addresses are collected in a group which is known by a single name.
Whenever a person sends a mail , everyone in the group gets a copy of the mail.
We can subscribe to a mailing list of our interest and then sens/receive mails to/from the group.